# SlidingEventTimeWindows does not produce any output

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a stream execution configured as

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataStreamSource<Record> stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer(
    SystemsCpu.TOPIC,
    ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forGeneric(SystemsCpu.SCHEMA, registry),
    config)
    .setStartFromLatest());

DataStream<Anomaly> anomalies = stream
    .keyBy(x -> x.get("host").toString())
    .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(20), Time.seconds(20))) // produces output with TumblingEventTimeWindows
    .process(new AnomalyDetector())
    .name("anomaly-detector");
```

```java
public class AnomalyDetector extends ProcessWindowFunction<Record, Anomaly, String, TimeWindow> {

  @Override
  public void process(String key, Context context, Iterable<Record> input, Collector<Anomaly> out) {
    var anomaly = new Anomaly();
    anomaly.setValue(1.0);
    out.collect(anomaly);
  }
}
```

However for some reason `SlidingEventTimeWindows` does not produce any output to be processed by the `AnomalyDetector` (i.e. process is not triggered at all). If I use, for example, `TumblingEventTimeWindows` it works as expected.

Any ideas what might be causing this? Am I using `SlidingEventTimeWindows` incorrectly?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @PiotrWittchen see accepted answer

Comment: I've seen this answer, but I also want to unit test this window and this answer is unfortunately not sufficient for that.

Comment: The accepted answer refers to out of date information, and is somewhat misleading. See my comment below.

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks, what you mentioned makes sense and works. If you would like to provide a more up-to-date answer in addition to the comment, I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing any sort of event time windowing it is necessary to provide a `WatermarkStrategy`. Watermarks mark a spot in the stream, and signal that the stream is complete up through some specific point in time. Event time windows can only be triggered by the arrival of a sufficiently large watermark.

See [the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/) for details, but this could be something like this:

```java
DataStream<MyType> timestampedEvents = events
  .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
      WatermarkStrategy
        .<MyType>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.timestamp));
```

However, since you are using Kafka, it's usually better to have the Flink Kafka consumer do the watermarking:

```java
FlinkKafkaConsumer<MyType> kafkaSource = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("myTopic", schema, props);

kafkaSource.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy...);

DataStream<MyType> stream = env.addSource(kafkaSource);
```

Note that if you use this later approach, and if your events are in temporal order within each Kafka partition, you can take advantage of the per-parition watermarking that the Flink Kafka source provides, and use `WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps()` rather than the bounded-of-orderness strategy. This has a number of advantages.

By the way, and this is unrelated to your question, but you should be aware that by specifying `SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(20), Time.seconds(20))`, every event will be copied into each of 60 overlapping windows.

Comment: Thanks! By using `SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(20), Time.seconds(20))` I am trying to achieve a "lookback" of 20 minutes every 20 seconds (for running a density based algorithm on the data).  Is that the correct way of doing that or again I am on the wrong path?

Comment: You have correctly understood what sliding windows do. Just alerting you to the fact that they are expensive. You may be able to implement a more efficient solution by, for example, having a first stage that computes 20-second aggregates (if that's compatible with how the density-based algorithm works).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `SlidingEventTimeWindows` but your stream execution environment is configured for processing time by default. Either use `SlidingProcessingTimeWindows` or configure your environment for event time like so

`env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)`

Event time will also require a special time stamp assigner, you can find more info here.

https://www.ververica.com/blog/stream-processing-introduction-event-time-apache-flink?hs_amp=true

Comment: Thanks so much! `setStreamTimeCharacteristic` is deprecated so I think `SlidingProcessingTimeWindows` is the best way to go.

Comment: `setStreamTimeCharacteristic` was deprecated because event time is now the default. But to use event time you need to define a `WatermarkStrategy`: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/